# Webhook call failed. Error: Failed to parse webhook JSON response: Expect message object but got null

Tags: php, dialogflow-es

I have written fulfillment linking database to MySQL database but dialogflow returns the status Webhook call failed. Error: Failed to parse webhook JSON response: Expect message object but got :null. I am supposed to add user input into MySQL database.

I have tried to look into json formats for v1 and v2 without much of a breakthrough.

```
<?php
function sendMessage($parameters)
{
    $jsonencodeparameters = json_encode($parameters);

    echo json_encode(parameters);
}

function debug_text ($namafile, $contentdebug)
{
    $myfile = fopen ($namafile, w) or die ("unable to open file");
    fwrite ($myfile, $contentdebug);
    fclose($myfile);
}

function add_data ($first_name,$last_name, $policy_number, $link,$mySQLserver,$mySQL)
{
    $sql = "insert into users ('firstname','lastname','policynumber') values ('first_name','last_name','policy_number')";
    $namafile = "add.txt";
    $contentdebug = "sql=".$sql;
    debug_text($namafile,$contentdebug);
    $last_id =0;
    try
    {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host = $mySQLserver,dbname = $mySQLdefaultdb",$mySQLserver,$mySQLpassword);
        $conn = setAttribute (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $conn->exec($sql);
        $last_id = $conn->lastinsertId();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $last_id = 0;

    }
return last_id;
}




include ('db_regusers.php');
include ('function_regusers.php');
$update_response = file_get_contents('php://input');
$update = json_decode($update_response, true);
$varresultaction = $update['queryResult']["action"];
$fulfillmentMessages = $update["queryResult"]["queryText"];
$session = $update["session"];
$firstname = $update['queryResult']['parameters']['firstname'];
$lastname=$update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["lastname"];
$policynumber=$update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["policynumber"];
$ignore1 = '';
$sessionunique = '';

if ($session != '')
{
    $list = list($ignore1,$sessionunique) = explode('sessions/',$session);

}
else
{
    $nothing = 'You do not have a session';
    sendMessage(array(
    'source'=>null,
    'fulfillmentText'=>$nothing
));
exit;
}

}
if($varresultaction == 'entry_data')
{
    $id = add_data($firstname,$lastname,$policynumber,$mySQLserver,mySQLdefaultdb,mySQLuser,mySQLserver,mySQLpassword);
    $response = 'data has been saved, your access_code is' +'.$id';
    sendMessage (array(
    'source'=> null,
    'fulfillmentText'=>$response));
    exit;
}
```

Comment: So what version is what you have shown supposed to be then, v1 or v2? For v2, the property should be named `fulfillment_text`, according to https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#webhookresponse (the dialogflow docs link there), but you are supplying `fulfillmentText` – so unless there is any magic camel case / underscore conversion happening in the background, that looks rather wrong to me.

Comment: Wow, the new docs are inconsistent. Yes, there is conversion that goes on in the background. But in the past, both camelCase and snake_case were valid for the results, although they were consistent in using camelCase for the docs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have a logic problem with your code. You are only sending a response in two conditions:

- There is no session information
- The Action name is "entry_data"

For the Welcome Intent, Fallback Intents, or any other Intent - nothing will be sent, so you will generate an error.

Comment: i have also written code for editing and deleting data in the database but had to omit it for brevity. I have similarly handled all the other intents using respective action names. I have no idea how to handle the session information though. Any suggestions on how I might work around that

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by handling the session information.

Comment: I want to get the parameters from each session and add to the database and avoid a situation where user input from different usets gets mixed up when writing to the database

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `source` to `null` explicitly, rather than setting it to a string, seems odd. Since `source` is listed as optional, you can just omit it completely, otherwise just set it to a string.